# I want to see Form validation message when it is submitted blank

Tags: javascript, validation

I have problem with form validation using javascript. I would like to see following message in my form when I submit it blank
[image]

By using following html and javascript code but it's not showing and I am failing to handle it where is the problem .

```js
<!-- javascript code -->

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function validate(){
  
  
  if(document.frm.username.value == ""){
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Fill up the username.";
   document.frm.username.focus();
   return false;
  }

  
  if(document.frm.password.value ==""){
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Fill up the password.";
   document.frm.password.focus();
   return false;
  }
 
  if(document.frm_validate.confirmPassword.value == ""){
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Fill up the confirm password.";
   document.frm.confirmPassword.focus();
   return false;
  }
 
  if(document.frm_validate.firstName.value == ""){
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Fill up the first name.";
   document.frm.firstName.focus();
   return false;
  }


  if(document.frm_validate.email.value == ""){
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Fill up the email.";
   document.frm.email.focus();
   return false;
  }

  return true;
 }

 


 </script>
```

```html
  <!-- form validation -->

                <form class="form-horizontal frm_validate" name="frm" action="#" onsubmit="validate()">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Form Validation</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username<span class="star">  *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="username">
                                <span id="text"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password<span class="star">  *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="....." type="text" name="password">
                                <span id="text"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Confirm Password<span class="star">  *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="....." type="text" name="confirmPassword">
                                <span id="text"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">First Name<span class="star">  *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="firstName">
                                <span id="text"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastName" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email<span class="star">  *</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email">
                                <span id="text"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

      <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                <p><span class="star">*  </span>Required field</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>




                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: So you need to run the function when the user presses the submit button?

Comment: onsubmit="return validate()"

Comment: @nevermind would my solution not work? I'm just curious why it would require `onsubmit` instead of what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @Script47, try it, i think - no.

Comment: @Script47—to cancel the submit event, the listener must return *false* to the handler. Currently it will return *undefined* regardless of what your function returns.

Comment: @RobG or e.preventDefault(); right?

Comment: Also, there are more problems, you have multiple ID's - it is not allowed. And, i guess you want to show ALL errors on submit, rather than first one/one by one, and then stop script? In that case, instead return false; you will have to collect errors info (in array, maybe), and depending on it - show error messages/or submit form.

Comment: @Script47—sure, but the OP doesn't have a reference to the related event object.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an inline listener, it is effectively wrapped in a function:

```
<form onsubmit="foo()" ...>
```

effectivley creates a listener like:

```
onsubmit = function () {
  foo();
}
```

note that there is no return statement, so the listener returns *undefined*. To get the listener to return *false* and hence cancel the submit event, you must include a return statement, so:

```
    <form onsubmit="return foo()" ...>
```

becomes:

```
onsubmit = function () {
  return foo();
}
```

so now the listener returns the value returned by the function.